# Linux Mint 18 - Enable Kinetic Scroll / Scroll Coasting

Tags: linux-mint, scrolling

How can I enable MacOS-like scroll momentum for the trackpad with Linux Mint 18?

Answer (score 3):

New Linux Mint versions use the libinput driver instead of the synaptics driver by default, and libinput doesn't support kinetic scrolling:
https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/faqs.html#kinetic-scrolling-does-not-work

To switch to the synaptics driver:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Comment: The explanation is actually very right: it was a pain that the scroll moved to another window when switching. Or even more annoying, one start pressing `Ctrl` and then zoom is activated. The later was the worse, if it could have been possible to add a rule like "ignore keys in the later events" it would have been good enough. 
I now realize I miss the feature, but I also support the "if it doesn't work properly then let's make it at all" motion.

Comment: You should add a warning to this answer. On the Linux Mint 20.3 this causes the keyboard to completely stop working.

Answer (score 2):

A warning - on switching to the Synaptics driver as in the answer above (on a Lenovo Yoga 7i Creative) and rebooting, my keyboard no longer worked.

To fix, I had to boot off the install ISO, chroot as per the 'Update failure' section in [Ubuntu's Live CD recovery page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery), then remove the synaptics driver and re-add the libinput one.

Comment: Ran into the same problem. I wish this post would get updated or have an edit. Many other users will run into that problem.

Fortuntely I was able to get the keyboard working again by using the Accessibility On-Screen keyboard to revert those two commands.